# Editar Celula de uma Table

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Galera, estou precisando de uma ajuda, estou preenchendo uma tabela com um resultado de um `Select SQL`. Como mostra o código abaixo:

```
$sql = "SELECT Nome, COUNT(Especialidades_idEspecialidades)
FROM especialidades_has_professores AS ehp,
professores AS p,
professores_has_universidade AS phu,
universidades AS u
WHERE ehp.Professores_idProfessores = p.idProfessores
AND phu.Professores_idProfessores = p.idProfessores
AND phu.Universidades_idUniversidades = u.idUniversidades
AND u.DistanciaAtual < '$raio'
AND p.nome != '$orientador'
AND ehp.Especialidades_idEspecialidades IN (
    SELECT Especialidades_idEspecialidades
    FROM especialidades_has_temas AS eht
    WHERE eht.Temas_idTemas = '$idTemas'
)
GROUP BY ehp.Professores_idProfessores
ORDER BY COUNT(Especialidades_idEspecialidades) DESC
LIMIT $numero ";

foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row ) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></td>';
    echo '<td>'. $row['Nome'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<a class="btn btn-app">';
    echo ' <i class="fa fa-repeat"></i> Trocar Professor';
    echo '</a>';
    echo '</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo '<a class="btn btn-app">';
    echo '<span class="badge bg-aqua">Email Enviado</span>';
    echo '<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Enviar';
    echo '</a>';
    echo '</td>';    
    echo '</tr>';
}
?>
```

Na tabela exite um botao de `Troca`, e na hora que aciona-se esse botão, eu queria fazer um troca com um outro resultado de um `Select SQL`. Como posso fazer isso? Tentei várias formas sem nenhum resultado.

Comment: Já tentou usar DataTables?

Comment: Não entendi o que você realmente quer. Poderia tentar explicar melhor por favor.

Comment: Parece que a consulta dele retorna um professor cadastrado, e esse botão ficaria encarregado de trazer algum outro professor (aleatório, creio eu) do banco, basicamente, substituir o professor atual por outro.

Comment: Olá Paulo, 
Pelo que entendi do que você colocou você deseja implementar a função de troca de professor, ai tem que ser pensado, quando clicar em troca o que tem que acontecer, abrir um menu para escolher outro professor e clicar em OK, remover o professor, abrir outra página, é necessário saber o que se deseja para fazer, uma vez definido fica fácil saber o que precisa ser feito se você precisará de novas queries, novos scripts e assim por diante.

Comment: Desculpe a demora pessoal, obrigado pela respostas... então era realmente isso que eu queria fazer Eduardo Silva e ooredroxxo, eu queria usar um modal para trazer novos professores, mas acabei usando uma 'gabiarra' assim q clico no botão trocar professor minha div muda para um input com autocomplete onde escolho um novo professor

Comment: Fiz isso utilizando javaScript :))